# raise ValueError('No user has "{}" as username' ValueError: No user has "bvbjjkhjb" as username

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

help me..i'm just learning python and i'm having a problem in my code..an error like this raise ValueError('No user has "{}" as username' ValueError: No user has "bvbjjkhjb" as username. how to keep the code running to the next username when there is an invalid username. my code is like this

```
    for user in users:

        if mode == 2:

            if user['username'] == "":

                continue

            receiver = client.get_input_entity(user['username'])

        elif mode == 1:

            receiver = InputPeerUser(user['id'],user['access_hash'])

        else:

            print(re+"[!] Invalid Mode. Exiting.")

            client.disconnect()

            sys.exit()

        try:

            print(gr+"[+] Sending Message to:", user['name'])

            client.send_message(receiver, data.format(user['name']))

            print(gr+"[+] Waiting {} seconds".format(SLEEP_TIME))

            time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)

        except PeerFloodError:

            print(re+"[!] Getting Flood Error from telegram. \n[!] Script is stopping now. \n[!] Please try again after some time.")

            client.disconnect()

            sys.exit()

        except Exception as e:

            print(re+"[!] Error:", e)

            print(re+"[!] Trying to continue...")

            continue

    client.disconnect()

    print("Done. Message sent to all users.")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
except ValueError as e:
    if str(e) == '...':
        continue
```

Or use a regexp match instead of `==`:

```
import re
...
except ValueError as e:
    if re.match(r'No user has "[^"]*" as username[.]\Z', str(e)):
        continue
    raise
```